# Android view.setX()/setY() according accelerometer changes, show motion trail animation

Tags: android, view, android-animation

I am trying to implement something like:
motion trail animation
motion blur animation
ghost animation
(i do not know correct name of "effect") for repeatedly change view position.

Function, which is called repeatedly according accelerometer changes:

```
public void setXY(float x, float y) {
    if(view != null) {
        overloadPoint.setX(pointX);
        overloadPoint.setY(pointY);
    }
}
```

My goal:
For change X,Y animation show path (line, curve) between old and new view position.

OR alternative goal:
Between old and new view position, i would like to freeze old position and apply for example alpha effect to view in old position from 1.0f to 0.0f, duration:100ms. So when method is called for example every 50ms, i will see two views. Both views will have fade out effect (alpha 1.0f -> 0.0f), but older will have less alpha.

For: API >= 21

I tried:

```
public void setXY(float x, float y){
    final View view = new View(this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            25, //TODO
            25)); //TODO
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_point);
    relativeLayout.addView(view);
    view.setX(x);
    view.setY(y);

    //Variant 1:
    view.animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(750)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
            .withLayer()
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    relativeLayout.removeView(view);
                }
            })
            .start();

    //Variant 2:
    /*AlphaAnimation anim1 = new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
    anim1.setDuration(750);
    //anim1.setFillAfter(true);
    anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {};
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim){};
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
            relativeLayout.removeView(view);
        };
    });
    view.startAnimation(anim1);*/

    //Variant 3:
    /*view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ALPHA, 0f);
    // Add a listener that does cleanup
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            relativeLayout.removeView(view);
            view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        }
    });
    animator.start();*/
}
```

But i think, that these are not good solutions.. repeatedly create and remove Views. Better will be effect with one View.

Thank you.